# How to disable a button on click and replace that button with another button with different function using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, button

How to disable a button on click and replace that button with another button with different function using AngularJS?
The following is my button,

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-default"
ng-disabled="isteam==0 || secondEdit" ng-click="editSetting()">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>&nbsp;Edit Setting</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a state setting, say `$scope.showFirstButton=true` to control when to show the submit button:

```
<button ng-show="showFirstButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-default" ng-disabled="isteam==0 || secondEdit" ng-click="editSetting()">Edit Setting</button>
```

and another button, showing them alternatively:

```
<button ng-show="!showFirstButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-default" ng-click="doSomethingElse()">Seccond Button</button>
```

In the controller method `$scope.editSetting()` you change the value of the state: `$scope.showFirstButton = !$scope.showFirstButton'`.

**Edit**: if you need to revert the state of the buttons, do the same thing in the second method:

```
$scope.doSomethingElse = function(){
  //some cool things happen here, and:
  $scope.showFirstButton = !$scope.showFirstButton
}
```

and this will get back the first button and hide the second.

Comment: Thats great bosch, what if on click the next button, i want to revert the previous button?

Comment: Oh yeah! Thanks bosch. Sorry for the stupid doubt after that fruitful info